# GWT/GXT grid with local pagination?

Tags: java, gwt, extjs, gxt

I am using GXT grid with local pagination( http://www.sencha.com/examples-2/#localpaging ).
i can get 2000 records from database and all will be in memory and only first page records are shown to the user and next set of results are pulled from memory and shown.

My question is, the memory where i am keeping all 2000 records refers to client machine's memory or Application server's memory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is client machine's memory. If you look at the example, all the records to be shown into the grid are loaded into PagingModelMemoryProxy instance

```
PagingModelMemoryProxy proxy = new PagingModelMemoryProxy(TestData.getStocks());
```